# Windows authentication to get data from SQL Server via a Python REST API?

Tags: python, fastapi, windows-authentication

I am using a SQL Server database, that uses Windows authentication to implement row-level security.

I would like to make the data accessible on a website, by implementing APIs in Python (e.g. with FastAPI, Flask), considering the windows user, who is accessing the API.

How can I use windows authentication in FastAPI/Flask, and then forward that authenticated user to the SQL Server?